# Pandas groupby cumcount starting on row with a certain column value

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to create two cumcount columns, depending on the values of two columns.

In the example below, I'd like one cumcount starting when colA is at least 100, and another cumcount starting when colB is at least 10.

```
columns = ['ID', 'colA', 'colB', 'cumcountA', 'cumountB']
data = [['A', 3, 1, '',''],
    ['A', 20, 4, '',''],
    ['A', 102, 8, 1, ''],
    ['A', 117, 10, 2, 1],
    ['B', 75, 0, '',''],
    ['B', 170, 12, 1, 1],
    ['B', 200, 13, 2, 2],
    ['B', 300, 20, 3, 3],     
   ]

pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=data)

    ID  colA    colB    cumcountA   cumountB
0   A   3   1       
1   A   20  4       
2   A   102 8   1   
3   A   117 10  2   1
4   B   75  0       
5   B   170 12  1   1
6   B   200 13  2   2
7   B   300 20  3   3
```

How would I calculate `cumcountA` and `cumcountB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try setting `df.clip` `lower` = `your values` (here 100 and 10) and then compare then groupby `ID` and `cumsum` :

```
col_list = ['colA','colB']
val_list = [100,10]

df[['cumcountA','cumountB']] = (df[col_list].ge(df[col_list].clip(lower=val_list,axis=1))
                                 .groupby(df['ID']).cumsum().replace(0,''))
print(df)
```

Or may be even better to compare directly:

```
df[['cumcountA','cumountB']] = (df[['colA','colB']].ge([100,10])
                               .groupby(df['ID']).cumsum().replace(0,''))
print(df)
```

---

```
  ID  colA  colB cumcountA cumountB
0  A     3     1                   
1  A    20     4                   
2  A   102     8         1         
3  A   117    10         2        1
4  B    75     0                   
5  B   170    12         1        1
6  B   200    13         2        2
7  B   300    20         3        3
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Can you explain a bit why this works with `ge`?

Comment: @robroc `ge` is greater than or equal to. we compare if the columns are ge the list values and then groupby ID column